# jQuery animation to the left won't trigger after the div is animated to the right

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

So I made a simple animation in jquery where I animate two rows of images by clicking on the left/right arrows, which moves them to left or right. Now the problem is strange, when I click on the right arrow after loading, the animation works fine and the div with images is animated to the right and returns to it's original position. But when I try to click on the left arrow immediately afterwards, the images won't animate to the left. However, if I press the left arrow and then right, the animation works well enough. So basically after animating to the right there's no turning back and the left arrow doesn't work.

I'm not sure what might be the problem but I've tried animating different elements in the same way and noticed that it's impossible for me to animate the element to the left after animating it to the right (and returning to the initial position). I would appreciate if you could help me with this, I'm still pretty new to jQuery so I might've done a dumb mistake without noticing.

Here's the whole codepen: 
https://codepen.io/Ellie555/pen/EBKPVp

I tried a lot of different things, I've previously thought the problem is in the fact that after the animation ends I switch the order of the first and last image in the row, but even after deleting that part the animation still doesn't work properly. I tried switching the order of functions and putting it all under one function, still didn't help.

```
var distance = $('.first-row').children().last().outerWidth();
var images = $('.img-item');

$('.arrow-right').click(function(){
    images.animate({left: distance},400, function(){
        images.css('left', '0px'); 
    });
});


$('.arrow-left').click(function(){
    images.animate({right: distance},400, function(){
        images.css('right', '0px');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The css "right" doesn't mean to get the coordinates of the element some pixels from the right, but it is counted from right to left, so right: 0px; is at the right of the screen. left: 0px; isat the left of the screen. So if you gave the element a css right property, the left won't have any effect. Try: 
for the left click:

```
images.animate({left: '+=' + distance}, 400)
```

or
for the right click:

```
images.animate({left: '-=' + distance}, 400)
```

I hope I helped you.